# Why my ajax request always throws error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

**PHP:**

```
public function export(Request $request){

    $file = "export.txt";
    if(isset($_POST["type"])){
        file_put_contents("$file",$_POST["text"]);
    }
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // the appropriate header type for txt file
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
    $(document).on('click', '#export', function () {
        var names =  ['علی','فرید'];
        var namess = names.join('\n');
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/export",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: {
                type: "save",
                text: namess
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){
                var href = '/export?filename=export.txt';
                window.location = href;
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('wrong');
            }
        });
    })
```

Always `error` part executes. I mean it always alert `wrong`. How can I fix it? All I'm trying to do it making a `.txt` download file.

Noted that when I run this path: `http://localhost:8000/export?filename=export.txt` .. then `export.txt` will be downloaded.

Comment: What's in your export.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download using this code:

```
window.location="export?filename=export.txt";
```

If you want to post data :

```
   $('<form action="comments.php" method="POST"/>')
        .append($('<input type="hidden" name="type" value="save">'))
       .append($('<input type="hidden" name="text" value="'+ namess +'">'))
        .appendTo($(document.body)) //it has to be added somewhere into the <body>
        .submit();
```

Full code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#export', function () {

    var names =  ['علی','فرید'];
    var namess = names.join('\n');

     $('<form action="export?filename=export.txt" method="POST"/>')
        .append($('<input type="hidden" name="type" value="save">'))
       .append($('<input type="hidden" name="text" value="'+ namess +'">'))
        .appendTo($(document.body)) //it has to be added somewhere into the <body>
        .submit();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically Ajax is not usually used for file download however you can tune to make it feel and that is what you have done the only thing is when the request is successful us a "document.location" function from javascript to popup a new window for downloading a file. Besides for the error you are getting, try debugging your PHP code by playing around with your PHP header by starting with most important PHP Headers such as

```
    


    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($fileName);
    exit;
```

check you code works with minimal information if it works then start adding more header one at a time, this helps in resolving problem with minimal information. 
Hope this helps.